# VIM: how to match only certain lines

Tags: vim, selection, match, highlight, lines

I can't find out how to match the entire line of only certain lines p.e.

How can I match (and highlight) every other 3 lines from lines 10 till 25:

match
line 10,11,12
line 16,17,18
line 22,23,24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hm, the pragmatic way would be to define a function that runs over your file and matches all lines you'd like. Something like this:

```
fun! <sid>HiLines(steps) range                                                 
    for line in range(a:firstline,a:lastline,6)                                
        call matchadd('Search', join(map(range(line,line+a:steps-1), '''\%'' . v:val . ''l'''), '\|'))                                                           
    endfor                                                                     
endfun                                                                         

com! -range=% -nargs=1 HiLines :<line1>,<line2>call <sid>HiLines(<f-args>)
```

Now use e.g. `:10,25HiLines 3` to match every other 3 lines from 10 till 25.

(Adjust highlighting group to taste).

Comment: Christian where do you declare the variable `v:va+l`?  Do you know what do I have to change to alternate 3 lines (matched) and 2 lines (non matched)?

Comment: v:val is a built-in vim variable, so I think `v:va+l` must be a typo.  Try taking the + out.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
:match Search /\%10l\|\%11l\|\%12l/
```

will highlight lines 10, 11 and 12